# Replacing "-" with "-1*" using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have string as below,

```
string str  =  "FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10) + FML("Test - KB")";
```

I would like to replace the "-" with "-1 * ". However it should not apply to literal string. For example. FML("Test - KB") should NOT be changed to FML("Test -1 * KB").

The desired output is   "FX(Y + 1, -1 * (5 * 10) + FML("Test - KB")".

Is there a way to do this in regular expression?

Any advice/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10) + FML(\"Test - KB\")",
                           "(?<=^([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*)-",
                           "-1 * ");
```

Regex explanation:

```
(?<=        # preceded by..
^           # the start of the string, then
([^"]       # either not a " character
|"[^"]*"    # or a string: "..."
)*          # as many times as you want
)
-           # then match the hyphen
```

Output for your example string is:

```
FX(Y + 1, -1 * (5 * 10) + FML("Test - KB")
```

(Note that this doesn't handle string escapes, if they are supported in your target language.)

This solution will handle strings properly, not just with a heuristic. Here is an example:

```
FX(Y+1, -(X+Y) + "EMBEDDED: FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10)" - (X+Y)
```

Becomes:

```
FX(Y+1, -1 *(X+Y) + "EMBEDDED: FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10)" -1 * (X+Y)
```

Note that the string is not touched even though it "looks like" the other parts.

Comment: Dont you think its way too complicated?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Not really, that's the simplest solution I can think of that solves his problem correctly. e.g. it works on this string without touching anything in quotes: `FX(Y+1, -(X+Y) + "EMBEDDED: FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10)" - (X+Y)`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: it fails if the inner string was to contain the sequence "-(", like the example I just showed.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you could replace `-(` with `-1*(`, that seems to be what you want, but it really depends upon your exact string.  For instance, in your example, the `Test - KB` would never have the - replaced, because it is not part of the string, it is instead a calculation which gets added to the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(?=[^"]*(?:[^"]*\"[^"]*\"[^"]*)*$)
```

The preceding Regex string will match every minus sign that isn't followed by an even number or zero ". So it will match the minus sign in this strings:

```
abc - dssda dsda asd
ab - dssd ds F(" sdds ")
fhdhhf - asd F("ssd") sdsd D("dsfdf")
```

This ensures that the minus sign that is being replaced isn't contained in a string literal. Here is an example in C#.

```
string input = "FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10) + FML(\"Test - KB\")";
string replacement = "-1 *";
Regex rgx = new Regex("-(?=[^\"]*(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*$)");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex to match only "-" that is placed by "("

[^-]+(-)(?:()[^-]

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string str  =  "FX(Y + 1, -(5 * 10) + FML(\"Test - KB\")";
string r = new Regex("-[(]").Replace(str,"-1*(");
```

this code finds -( and replace with -1*(